# Employee-Supervisor Sorting in R

Tags: r

I am working with employee data.  The overall data frame has 104 columns, but for this, I am only concerned about two columns.  We have an employee number and their supervisor (in the form of a supervisor ID that exists in the employee ID column).  I need to sort the data, so that the employee number is above any instance of it in the supervisor id column.

Below is my first stab at a solution, but it has a couple of issues and I presume there is a better way at doing it.  Right now, it is not just moving the row up, it is adding a new row, so it will never complete.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
library(iterators)
EmpNo <- c(1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118)
SupervisorID <- c(1118, 1117, 1114, 1112, 1112, 1118, 1117, 1117)
supervisors <- data.frame(EmpNo, SupervisorID)

loop <- TRUE
while(loop)
{
  loop <- FALSE
  iSupervisor <- iter(supervisors, by ='row')
  for(i in 1:nrow(supervisors))
  {
    tempElem <- nextElem(iSupervisor)
    if(nrow(tempElem) == 1)
    {
      # It does not properly move the row.
      if(i > 1)
      {
        if(nrow(supervisors[tempElem$EmpNo %in% supervisors[1:(i-1),"SupervisorID"]]) > 0)
        {
          if(length(which(supervisors$SupervisorID == tempElem$EmpNo)) != 0)
          {
            sup.first <- min(which(supervisors$SupervisorID == tempElem$EmpNo))
            if(sup.first > i)
            {
              loop <- TRUE
              if(i == nrow(supervisors))
              {
                if(sup.first == 1)
                {
                  supervisors <- rbind(supervisors[i,],supervisors[1:(i-1),])
                } else
                {
                  supervisors <- rbind(supervisors[1:(sup.first-1),],supervisors[i,],supervisors[sup.first:(i-1),])
                }
              } else
              {
                if(sup.first == 1)
                {
                  supervisors <- rbind(supervisors[i,],supervisors[1:(i-1),], supervisors[(i+1):nrow(supervisors),])
                } else
                {
                  supervisors <- rbind(supervisors[1:(sup.first-1),],supervisors[i,],supervisors[sup.first:nrow(supervisors),])
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if(nrow(supervisors) > 50) { loop <- FALSE }
  }
  rownames(supervisors) <- NULL
}
```

UPDATE:
There is one that is the head supervisor.  Their SupervisorID is the same as their EmpNo.  The sorting of the employee number is not relevant, except that it must be above anyone that reports to them.  Below is some sample data.

Initial Data:

```
EmpNo   SupervisorID
1111    1118
1112    1117
1113    1114
1114    1112
1115    1112
1116    1118
1117    1117
1118    1117
```

Desired Outcome:

```
EmpNo   SupervisorID
1117    1117
1118    1117
1112    1117
1111    1118
1116    1118
1114    1112
1115    1112
1113    1114
```

UPDATE:
Updated the code to make it fully reproducible, including a break to keep it from running infinitely.

Comment: could we have a *small* reproducible example?

Comment: Do the supervisors have supervisors?  In your desired solution,  is there anyone who is allowed to be first?  It would have to be someone with no supervisor.

Comment: Yes, the supervisors can have supervisors, and there is one that is the top.  I'll add some sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution I went with.  It is still a bit slow, but it solves the problem.

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))

EmpNo <- c(1111, 1112, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1116, 1117, 1118)
SupervisorID <- c(1118, 1117, 1114, 1112, 1112, 1118, 1117, 1117)
Status <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A')
check <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
supervisors <- data.frame(EmpNo, SupervisorID, Status, check, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

loop <- TRUE
while(loop)
{
  loop <- FALSE
  supervisors$check <- apply(supervisors[,c('EmpNo', 'check', 'Status')], 1, function(y) {
    if(y['Status'] %!in% c('T','N')){
      if(nrow(supervisors[y['EmpNo'] %in% supervisors[1:max(((as.numeric(y['check'])-1)),1),"SupervisorID"]]) > 0)
      {
        if(length(which(supervisors$SupervisorID == y['EmpNo'])) > 0)
        {
          sup.first <- min(which(supervisors$SupervisorID == y['EmpNo']))
          if(sup.first < as.numeric(y['check']))
          {
            loop <<- TRUE
          }
          sup.first - 1
        } else
        {
          nrow(supervisors)
        }
      }

    } else {
      nrow(supervisors)
    }
  } )
  supervisors <- supervisors[order(supervisors$check),]
  supervisors$check <- as.numeric(rownames(supervisors))
  rownames(supervisors) <- NULL
}
```